# Can I make apa6 \maketitle not print an abstract?

Tags: titles, abstract, apa6

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}

% PAPER SPECIFIC
\title{Example Paper}
\author{C.J. Steele}
\affiliation{University of LaTeX}
\abstract{Sample abstract of the paper}
\shorttitle{Example Paper}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

%%%

Fill out this part here, this is your paper

%%%

\end{document}
```

Based off of the sample, I'm looking for an option that would allow me to forgo printing the Abstract with `\maketitle`.  (i.e. I have a professor asking that I not include an abstract.)

I'm a LaTeX newb, but I did google and search these forums.  I found one question here but it was closed because no one was sure what was being asked.  I've tried to avoid the pitfalls of that question, so please be gentle.  ;-P

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As far as I can tell, `apa6` only issues a warning if there's no abstract, which can be safely ignored. So, just omit `\abstract{...}`.

Comment: awe snap!  I think you might be right.  Though, the answer provided by lockstep is more along the lines of what I was expecting (from the simple fact that everything in LaTeX seems to have some quality of magic that is beyond my reach. lol)

Comment: The simplest way is to add `%` before the abstract line (or lines) in the input. It will still be there, but invisible to LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg True. My solution may be useful in case of multi-paragraph abstracts (or badly formatted sourcecode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\renewcommand{\abstract}[1]{}` to your preamble. (The original definition is `\long\def\abstract#1{\long\def\@abstract{#1}}`, and the code snippets that are responsible for typesetting the abstract do so only if `\@abstract` is defined.)

(Note: I'm assuming that you're not concerned about warnings, but want some kind of "noprint" option without actually having to delete the `\abstract` content.)

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\renewcommand{\abstract}[1]{}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}

% PAPER SPECIFIC
\title{Example Paper}
\author{C.J. Steele}
\affiliation{University of LaTeX}
\abstract{Sample abstract of the paper}
\shorttitle{Example Paper}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

%%%

Fill out this part here, this is your paper

%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the abstract without the warning?