# How can I put the abstract on the title page with apa6?

Tags: apa6

I am working on lab report in for a psychology class. It has to be in the APA manuscript style except that the abstract is to be on the title page. I am using the apa6 .sty and I cannot figure out how to do this. The closest thing I have found to an answer was [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98408/can-i-make-apa6-maketitle-not-print-an-abstract), but this deals with removing the abstract whereas I want to remove the abstract *page* and move the abstract to the title page. Here is a sample of my code:

```
\documentclass[man, 11pt, babel english, helv]{apa6}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Lab: Hello World}
\shorttitle{Lab}
\author{Henry Elliott}
\affiliation{Oklahoma State University}
\abstract{    
    This is my abstract.
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
% My paper 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436), and thanks for providing a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the `apa6.cls` file and don't see any hook that is provided to change that behavior as `\maketitke` isues a `\newpage` just prior to the `abstract`.

So you could either

1. negate the effect of `\newpage` within `\maketitle`, or alternatively
2. modify the code that produces the title page and remove the `\newpage` in there prior to the where the `abstract` is output:

[image]

### Code: Patch `\newpage` within `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass[man, 11pt, babel english, helv]{apa6}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\let\OldMaketitle\maketitle
\let\OldNewpage\newpage
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
   \renewcommand\newpage{\let\newpage\OldNewpage}% <----- Eliminate the effect of first \newpage
   \OldMaketitle%
}


\title{Lab: Hello World}
\shorttitle{Lab}
\author{Henry Elliott}
\affiliation{Oklahoma State University}
\abstract{    
    This is my abstract.
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
% My paper 
\end{document}
```

### Code: Modify `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass[man, 11pt, babel english, helv]{apa6}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{
\@ifundefined{hrm}{}{\hrm}
 \check@author

  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{0.5in}

  \vspace*{1in}
  \@title%
  \ifapamodeman{%
    \@ifundefined{def@noextraspace}{%
      \vspace{0.25in}\\
    }{}
  }{%
    \vspace{0.25in}\\
  }

  \@ifundefined{apaSix@maskauthoridentity}{%  BDB

      \@ifundefined{@authorTwo}{
      \@author \\

      \@affil \vspace{0.25in} \\ }{
      \@ifundefined{@authorThree}{
      \@authorOne \\

      \@affilOne \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorTwo \\

      \@affilTwo \vspace{0.25in} \\ }{
      \@ifundefined{@authorFour}{
      \@authorOne \\

      \@affilOne \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorTwo \\

      \@affilTwo \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorThree \\

      \@affilThree \vspace{0.25in} \\ }{
      \@ifundefined{@authorFive}{       %% 2006/01/05 added as contributed by Aaron Geller
      \@authorOne \\

      \@affilOne \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorTwo \\

      \@affilTwo \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorThree \\

      \@affilThree \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorFour \\

      \@affilFour \vspace{0.25in} \\ }{ %% 2006/01/05 beginning of Aaron Geller contribution
      \@ifundefined{@authorSix}{ %% -- thp 2006/01/05
      \@authorOne \\

      \@affilOne \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorTwo \\

      \@affilTwo \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorThree \\

      \@affilThree \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorFour \\

      \@affilFour \vspace{0.2in} \\ %% thp corrected distance to non-final value of 0.2in
      \@authorFive \\

      \@affilFive \vspace{0.25in} \\ }{%% 2006/01/05 end of Aaaron Geller contribution
    %% --- thp 2006/01/05 beginning of six-author display
      \@authorOne \\

      \@affilOne \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorTwo \\

      \@affilTwo \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorThree \\

      \@affilThree \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorFour \\

      \@affilFour \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorFive \\

      \@affilFive \vspace{0.2in} \\
      \@authorSix \\

      \@affilSix \vspace{0.25in} \\ }}}}}
    %% --- thp 2006/01/05 end of six-author display
      \@ifundefined{@note}
       {\vspace*{\baselineskip} }
       {\@note}

  }{%  mask author identity -- show nothing in the author or author note space
  }

  \end{center}

  \@ifundefined{apaSix@maskauthoridentity}{
      \@ifundefined{@acks}
       {}
       {%
         \vfill%
         \begin{center}%
            \acksname%
         \end{center}%
         \protect\raggedright
         \setlength{\parindent}{0.4in}
         \indent\par\@acks%
       }
  }{%  mask author identity -- show nothing in the author or author note space
  }

  %\newpage% <--------------- Commented this out
  %BDB\hyphenpenalty 10000
  \fussy
  \@ifundefined{@abstract}{}{%
    \section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}% BDB
    \noindent\@abstract\par% BDB
    \@ifundefined{@keywords}{}{%
      \setlength{\parindent}{0.4in}% BDB
      \indent\textit{\keywordname:} \@keywords%
    }%
    \newpage
  }

  \@ifundefined{def@donotrepeattitle}{
    \section{\protect\normalfont{\@title}}
  }{}%
  \raggedright%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.4in}%
}

\makeatother

\title{Lab: Hello World}
\shorttitle{Lab}
\author{Henry Elliott}
\affiliation{Oklahoma State University}
\abstract{    
    This is my abstract.
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
% My paper 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Method one worked beautifully.